# Types of property 'children' are incompatible -MockedProvider

Tags: reactjs, typescript, graphql, react-apollo, apollo-client

```
test('check if home renders correctly', () => {


  const { getByText } = render( <MockedProvider  mocks={mocks} addTypename={false}> <Home/> </MockedProvider>);

});
```

**I have a red line under the MockedProvider with The error message** :

```
 Types of property 'children' are incompatible.
     Type '(string | Element)[]' is not assignable to type 'ReactElement<any, string | ((props: any) => ReactElement<any, string
| ... | (new (props: any) => Component<any, any, any>)> | null) | (new
 (props: any) => Component<any, any, any>)> | ... 7 more ... |
 undefined'.
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like this is an issue with Apollo's type signature. It should allow a ReactNode since it is a subset of ReactElement. A work around is to explicitly cast the type of children as ReactElement.

```
const { getByText } = render( <MockedProvider  mocks={mocks} addTypename={false}> <Home/> as ReactElement </MockedProvider>);
```